# jQuery Onclick Filter Only Working for First Item Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I'm trying to make a filter for my list and it is working as I wanted. However it is only working for the first filter and not the rest. I can't figure out why.

What I'm trying to achieve is so that clicking on the 'parent' filter would hide 'childList' list items that doesn't have the same 'gid' attribute as the selected parent.

My code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="parent" gid="2">2</li>
    <li class="parent" gid="3">3</li>
    <li class="parent" gid="4">4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="childList" gid="2">2.1</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="2">2.2</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="2">2.3</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="3">3.1</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="3">3.2</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="3">3.3</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="4">4.1</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
    background-color: green;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $('.parent').on('click', function() {
    $(this).select().toggleClass('selected')

    var gid = $(this).select().attr('gid')
    if ($(this).select().attr('class') == 'parent')
      $('.childList').show()
    else {
      console.log(gid)
      if ($('.childList').attr('gid') == gid)
        $('.childList').not('[gid="' + gid + '"]').hide()
    }
  })
})
```

Your input and assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said "filter" I assume it should work like this: when no filters are applied, show entire set of child items.

To wit:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.parent').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    // reset view
    $(".childList").show();

    // apply filter
    var selectedGids = $(".parent.selected").toArray().map(function(o) {
      return $(o).attr("gid");
    });
    if(selectedGids.length)
      $(".childList").filter(function() {
      var gid = $(this).attr("gid");
      return $.inArray(gid, selectedGids) == -1;
    }).hide();
  })
})
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="parent" gid="2">2</li>
  <li class="parent" gid="3">3</li>
  <li class="parent" gid="4">4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="childList" gid="2">2.1</li>
  <li class="childList" gid="2">2.2</li>
  <li class="childList" gid="2">2.3</li>
  <li class="childList" gid="3">3.1</li>
  <li class="childList" gid="3">3.2</li>
  <li class="childList" gid="3">3.3</li>
  <li class="childList" gid="4">4.1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used the function childreen() to loop all the childreen of ul. I also added a class to the ul in order to to that. In this example I just made and if to show current selected parent's childreen. But if you select two parents it shows nothing if you want to modify it just change the "if" sentence. At least with .childreen() function you can have each child in an array so I think is easier to decide what to do.

```
<ul class="childGid">
```

and javascript

```
      var listChildreen = $( "ul.childGid" ).children()

  for(var i = 0; i< listChildreen.length; i++) {
  console.log($(listChildreen[i]).attr('gid'));
        if ($(listChildreen[i]).attr('gid') != gid)
            $(listChildreen[i]).hide()
      }
```

all code: https://jsfiddle.net/x4zx2y37/2/

Answer (score -1):

Check the code below

```js
$('.childList').hide();

$(function() {
  $('.parent').on('click', function() {
    $(this).select().toggleClass('selected')

    var gid = $(this).attr('gid');
    
    $('.childList[gid="'+gid+'"]').toggle(200);
  });
});
```

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="parent" gid="2">2</li>
    <li class="parent" gid="3">3</li>
    <li class="parent" gid="4">4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="childList" gid="2">2.1</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="2">2.2</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="2">2.3</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="3">3.1</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="3">3.2</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="3">3.3</li>
    <li class="childList" gid="4">4.1</li>
</ul>
```